# Knockout binding fontawesome class

Tags: typescript, data-binding, knockout.js, javascript-databinding, knockout-3.4

[Exmaple of posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/opknL1m2/)

Hello,

I have a problem with binding CSS class of font-awesome into an  tag.

HTML:

```
    <div class="flex-no-shrink">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <div data-bind="foreach: toolbarButtons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-bind="enable: enabled, visible: visible, click: onClick">
                   <i class="fa" data-bind="css: { class: icon }"></i>
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> -->
                </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-bind="enable: enabled, visible: visible, click: onClick">
                     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
interface IToolbarButton {
    enabled: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    visible: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    icon: string;
    onClick();
}

export abstract class ViewModel {
       toolbarButtons: IToolbarButton[];

   constructor(){
   this.loadDefaultToolbar();
   }
   loadDefaultToolbar(): void {
        this.toolbarButtons = [];
        //add button
        this.toolbarButtons.push({
            enabled: knockout.pureComputed(() => true/*some internal logic*/),
            icon: 'fa fa-plus',//this is what I want to place inside <i> tag
            onClick: () => {/*some internal logic*/},
            visible: knockout.pureComputed(() => true/*some internal logic*/)
        });
        //other default buttons...
        }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**What is a correct way to bind in mine situation?**

[Exmaple of posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/opknL1m2/)

I tried base binding like **text** or just **css: { icon }** but they now work also.

Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `css` binding has two forms:

1. One which accepts an object with classes as property names and values as boolean expressions:

   ```
   css: {className: booleanExpression}
   ```

   ...where `className` is the name of the class to include if `booleanExpression` is true (it will be left out if `booleanExpression` is false).
2. One which lets you specify the class name(s) to include as a string:

   ```
   css: stringExpression
   ```

You've sort of tried to combine the two syntaxes; you want the second one. Unlike (mis)using the `attr` binding, this respects other classes added to the element. This feature of the `css` binding is [documented here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html#example-with-dynamic-classes) and can be found in the [source here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/css.js#L14).

Live Example:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  someClassName: "two",
})
```

```css
.one { background: yellow; }
.two { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="one" data-bind="css: someClassName">
  My type is red because the view model added a class name!
</div>
```

If you'd like to see/compare more examples, please leave a comment.

Comment: (Hope you don't mind the additions, I'm hoping to delete my answer at some point...)